# How to uninstall Mahout 0.8

Tags: maven, uninstallation, mahout

As I need parallel frequent pattern mining algorithm and Mahout 0.8 does not include it, I want to uninstall Mahout 0.8 and install mahout 0.7. I installed Mahout 0.8 manually by

mvn -DskipTests install -e

When I run "sudo apt-get purge mahout" I got error: Unable to locate package mahout

I want to know how to uninstall it.

Comment: Are you sure you installed Mahout with apt-get? This package is usually distributed via the Maven repository.

Comment: i did not use apt-get, i download mahout package directly and run mvn -DskipTests install -e

Comment: In case you installed Mahout 0.8 also with Maven there is nothing to uninstall. It can stay in your local Maven repository `~/.m2/repository/`. Just define Mahout 0.7 as your dependency for your application (in pom.xml).

Comment: If I uninstall Maven, will it be removed?

Comment: No, it will stay. If you really want to remove Mahout 0.7 jars from your computer you can remove `~/.m2/repository` (an overkill) or everything Mahout related from this directory. Note that you probably don't need/want to do this. It is just a local Maven repo (cached artifacts) which are used by Maven when resolving project dependencies. If you let Maven to use 0.7 it will use it (in general, but removing this directory won't help you in those corner cases anyway).

Comment: after runing mvn install for mahout 0.7 i got error : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.1:process (default) on project mahout: Error loading supplemental data models: Failed to create directory /usr/local/mahout-distribution-0.7/target -> [Help 1]

Comment: I download mahout 0.7 should I now define dependency in pom.xml? or after mvn install? and How do I define?